# Target wildcards in a shell command

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to create targets that depend on a list of files in a directory with the name of the target:

```
bin/%.out: src/%/ $(shell find src/%/* -type f -iname '*.cpp' -o -iname '*.hpp')
#   Build stuff here
```

However `shell find src/%/* ...`ends up expanding to `shell find src//* ...`. At first I thought it's because I could only have 1 target wildcard but even after removing the `src/%/`dependency it ended up with this same problem.

Some more context: my directory contains a 'src' directory, which contains directories. Each sub-directory of 'src' I treat as a "project". When I build, all object files should go in `out/src/projname`. I'm attempting to use `find` to recursively get all source and header files per project. All binaries will go in `bin/projname.out` and as such, the main dependencies are `.out` files in `bin` that have the same names as their project name. (if `src/abc` exists, `bin/abc.out` is a dependency of `all`).

So for each sub-directory in `src`, all source files are compiled and the object files are moved to `out/projname` which eventually will be linked to `bin/projname.out`.

- src

  - proj0

    - cpp/hpp files
  - proj1

    - cpp/hpp files
- out

  - src

    - proj0

      - object files
    - proj1

      - object files
- bin

  - proj0.out
  - proj1.out

Currently getting the list of projects and list of output files as follows:

```
SRCS := $(shell find src/* -maxdepth 0 -type d)
SRCS_OUT := $(patsubst src/%,bin/%.out,$(SRCS))
...
all: out/ bin/ $(SRCS_OUT)
```

Projects can contain sub-directories and such, which is why I'm using `find` in the code at the very top.

Comment: could I use macros and pass % to it and just return that entire part from the macro?

Comment: This won't work. You could probably use some trickery to fill a variable with all the source files you want, but I assume there would be an even better/cleaner solution if you could give some context.

Comment: Okay I've updated the question to provide hopefully some more useful information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not see how to do what you want with standard, portable, make features. But it is doable with advanced GNU make features:

```
define PROJECT_rule
CPPS_$(1) := $$(shell find src/$(1) -type f -iname '*.cpp')
HPPS_$(1) := $$(shell find src/$(1) -type f -iname '*.hpp')
OBJS_$(1) := $$(patsubst src/$(1)/%.cpp,out/src/$(1)/%.o,$$(CPPS_$(1)))

$$(OBJS_$(1)): out/src/$(1)/%.o: src/$(1)/%.cpp $$(HPPS_$(1))
    <compile recipe>

bin/$(1).out: $$(OBJS_$(1))
    <link recipe>
endef

PRJS := $(patsubst src/%,%,$(shell find src/* -maxdepth 0 -type d))

$(foreach p,$(PRJS),$(eval $(call PROJECT_rule,$(p))))
```

We first define a make variable (`PROJECT_rule`) that will be used as a template for any of your projects; in this template, `$(1)` will represent the name of your project. Then, we compute the list of projects (`PRJS`) and, finally, we iterate over the projects and process our template for each of them (`foreach-eval-call`).

Notes:

1. I assumed that each object file of a project depends on all header files of the same project. If it is not the case you will have to rework this a bit.
2. What is important to understand is that:

   - The `PROJECT_rule` variable is first processed by `call` to substitute `$(1)` with the project's name.
   - Then it is expanded recursively and completely (including the recipes) by `eval`. Recursively means that if we have:

     ```
     FOO = foo
     BAR = FOO
     BAZ = $($(BAR))
     QUX = $$(BAZ)
     ```

     `$($(BAR))` is expanded as `foo` while `$$(BAZ)` is expanded as `$(BAZ)`. Completely means that all parts of the `PROJET_rule` variable are expanded, even what is finally used as recipes (while when make parses a Makefile, it normally defers the expansion of the recipes to a later stage).
   - The result will be instantiated as regular make constructs, that is, it will be expanded once more as regular make constructs (not the recipes), before being evaluated.
3. So, as there will be two expansions of `PROJECT_rule`, some `$` signs must be escaped (`$$`). Please remember this when writing your own `<compile recipe>` and `<link recipe>`. If you want to use the `$@` or `$^` automatic variables, for instance, do not forget to write `$$@`. Example: if your compile recipe is:

   ```
   $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@
   ```

   write:

   ```
   $$(CPP) $$(CPPFLAGS) $$(INCLUDES) -c $$< -o $$@
   ```

   in the definition of `PROJECT_rule`. The first expansion will transform it in:

   ```
   $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@
   ```

   While, if you write:

   ```
   $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@
   ```

   the first expansion will transform it in something like:

   ```
   g++ -O3 -Iincludes/foobar -c  -o
   ```

   Note that, unless `CPP`, `CPPFLAGS` or `INCLUDES` have specific target-dependent definitions, you can also write:

   ```
   $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $$< -o $$@
   ```

   because the first expansion will transform it in something like:

   ```
   g++ -O3 -Iincludes/foobar -c $< -o $@
   ```

   which is also correct.
4. A bit more detailed explanation: for each project (e.g. `proj0`), `foreach` will produce:

   ```
   $(eval $(call PROJECT_rule,proj0))
   ```

   `call` will substitute `$(1)` with `proj0` in the `PROJECT_rule` definition, such that the parameter of `eval` will be:

   ```
   CPPS_proj0 := $$(shell find src/proj0 -type f -iname '*.cpp')
   HPPS_proj0 := $$(shell find src/proj0 -type f -iname '*.hpp')
   OBJS_proj0 := $$(patsubst src/proj0/%.cpp,out/src/proj0/%.o,$$(CPPS_proj0))

   $$(OBJS_proj0): out/src/proj0/%.o: src/proj0/%.cpp $$(HPPS_proj0)
       <compile recipe>

   bin/proj0.out: $$(OBJS_proj0)
       <link recipe>
   ```

   `eval` will expand it recursively and completely, leading to:

   ```
   CPPS_proj0 := $(shell find src/proj0 -type f -iname '*.cpp')
   HPPS_proj0 := $(shell find src/proj0 -type f -iname '*.hpp')
   OBJS_proj0 := $(patsubst src/proj0/%.cpp,out/src/proj0/%.o,$(CPPS_proj0))

   $(OBJS_proj0): out/src/proj0/%.o: src/proj0/%.cpp $(HPPS_proj0)
       <expanded compile recipe>

   bin/proj0.out: $(OBJS_proj0)
       <expanded link recipe>
   ```

   (each `$$` becomes `$`, **even in the recipes**). `eval` will then instantiate the result as regular make constructs and they will be parsed as regular make syntax. That is, the (simple) variables will be expanded immediately, the targets and prerequisites too, but not the recipes. The recipes will be expanded in a second phase, just before being passed to the shell and executed, if they are.
5. The compile rule is a *static pattern rule*. If you do not know this already you can read [this section](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html#Static-Usage) of the GNU make documentation.
6. Exercise: in the definition of `PROJECT_rule` you could replace `$$(shell...` by `$(shell...` but not `$$(patsubst...` by `$(patsubst...`. Why?

Comment: Yeah it definitely works but I might end up just having a target for each project specifically to keep it more portable (if I get on my Windows machine I'm not sure if msys' make will work with it).

Comment: [Paul's rule number 1](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/): *Use GNU make. Don’t hassle with writing portable makefiles, use a portable make instead!* GNU make is ported under Windows.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with GNU make (I actually started just yesterday) but in this part: `$$(OBJS_$(1)): out/src/$(1)/%.o: src/$(1)/%.cpp $$(HPPS_$(1))` is that just "chaining" targets? I don't entirely understand that line (the rest is fine apart from that). Like, the left side depends on the middle side which depends on the right side?

Comment: The section of the manual that I mentioned (note #5) explains this really well, I think. I do not think I could do better.