# Custom dependency filters for targets in makefiles

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am working with a legacy library and am trying to shoehorn in a bit of unit testing to help me with development. In working with that I have found that if I can create target specific filters on my dependencies, that would make adapting their makefiles to my unit tests a bit easier. Currently I would do something like this

```
    var_list = input1 input2
    out_list = $(var_list:%=%.txt)

    all_deps = dep1 dep2 dep3

    input1_filter = dep2
    input2_filter = dep1 dep3

    all: $(out_list)

    input1.txt: %.txt: % $(filter-out $(input1_filter),$(all_deps))
        @echo "reqs = $?"
        @echo "$< > $@"
        @echo $< > $@

    input2.txt: %.txt: % $(filter-out $(input2_filter),$(all_deps))
        @echo "reqs = $?"
        @echo "$< > $@"
        @echo $< > $@

    clean:
       @rm $(out_list)
```

Obviously the to rules for `input1.txt` and `input2.txt` are nearly identical, so it would be great if one could write

```
    var_list = input1 input2
    out_list = $(var_list:%=%.txt)

    all_deps = dep1 dep2 dep3

    input1_filter = dep2
    input2_filter = dep1 dep3

    all: $(out_list)

    $(out_list): %.txt: % $(filter-out $(%_filter),$(all_deps))
        @echo "reqs = $?"
        @echo "$< > $@"
        @echo $< > $@

    clean:
       @rm $(out_list)
```

Which means that for every target I make, I only need to specify a corresponding `_filter` variable and the makefile would take care of the rest. However I still haven't been able to get this to work. I found out that one can reference these variables in the body of the rule, e.g. one can write `$(filter-out $($<_filter),$(all_deps))` in the body but not in the dependency list.

Comment: I have never seen this `&(filter_out...` before (I mean, the `&` sign to call make functions). What make are you using?

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo, should be $, I'll fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreach-eval-call` (GNU make only) is an option:

```
var_list = input1 input2
out_list = $(var_list:%=%.txt)

all_deps = dep1 dep2 dep3

input1_filter = dep2
input2_filter = dep1 dep3

all: $(out_list)

define MY_rule
$(1).txt: $(1) $$(filter-out $$($(1)_filter),$$(all_deps))
    @echo "reqs = $$?"
    @echo "$$< > $$@"
    @echo $$< > $$@
endef
$(foreach v,$(var_list),$(eval $(call MY_rule,$(v))))

clean:
   @rm $(out_list)
```

Pay attention to the double `$$`, they are important. For a detailed explanation on this construct, please see [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45459103/target-wildcards-in-a-shell-command/45460866#45460866) to a similar question.

Edit: the function should be filter-out

Comment: Yes that seems to work, thank you. So I guess there is no way of expanding the pattern sub inside of the dependencies and also have it evaluate something. I've also fixed some of the typos in your answer that were originally my typos.

Comment: @JonasGlesaaen I do not understand your question. What do you mean by *the pattern sub inside of the dependencies* and *evaluate something*?

Comment: Basically when writing the dependencies I would expect $(%_filter) to pattern match to $(input1_filter) (as the stem in this case should be input1 or input2), which would then be looked up, but that does not seem to be the case. Maybe it prepends the local folder to the stem? E.g. that the stem is actually ./input1, meaning that it matches to $(./input1_filter), which is not a variable.

Comment: @JonasGlesaaen My mistake: I iterated over `out_list` instead of `var_list`. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks, I caught that myself and changed it locally when I tried getting your solution to work. So just before I accept the answer, do you know why $(%_filter) doesn't do what I would expect, or if there is any way of making that kind of logic work?

Comment: @JonasGlesaaen `$(%_filter)` does not work because the prerequisites are expanded immediately, while the stem of your static pattern rule is not yet known.