# GNU make nested generic rules

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I use make to automate numerical experiments. It is often the case that I have to simulate data that depends on multiple parameters.

For example, I may have the size of the reconstructed image as a parameter, the noise level as another and also the reconstruction algorithm as a third parameter.

As a concrete case, I may wish to reconstruct 512x512 and 1024x1024 images from 10% and 5% relative error in the data, all the four cases should be done with both FISTA and ISTA algorithms.

I know how to use patterns with %, $@ and $* in order to get what I want when there is only one parameter involved. So, it is easy to get the result for 1024x1024 images using FISTA for several error levels.

But how do I nest?

Comment: Pattern rules are useful when the parameters are in the name of the target. But why not have them as variables? It makes the solution much cleaner.

Comment: Because I want to write only one rule, th build process is the same for every experiment, so is is a pain to copy the whole rule and change the variables. Having them as variables can't help with that.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. Instead of `make ImageA66_512_RE10_ISTA`, you could `make ImageA66 SIZE=512 RE=10 ALG=ISTA`. One simple rule covers all cases. Would that satisfy?

Comment: doesn't look like it helps, I'll try to understand your comment better

Answer (score 1):

If what you want (not 100% sure) is to loop over all possible cases, and if the command to launch for each case is:

```
echo simulate SIZE RELATIVE_ERROR ALGORITHM
```

then you could try something like:

```
# sizes
S := 512 1024
# relative errors
E := 5 10
# algorithms
A := FISTA ISTA
# targets
T :=

.PHONY: all
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

# $(1): size, $(2): error, $(3): algo
define MY_rule
T += $(1)-$(2)-$(3)
.PHONY: $(1)-$(2)-$(3)

$(1)-$(2)-$(3):
    @echo simulate $(1) $(2) $(3)
endef

$(foreach s,$(S),$(foreach e,$(E),$(foreach a,$(A),$(eval $(call MY_rule,$(s),$(e),$(a))))))

all: $(T)
```

It makes use of an advanced GNU make feature, the `foreach-eval-call` combination. [This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45459103/target-wildcards-in-a-shell-command/45460866#45460866) explains it in details.

Comment: I will try it and will give you feedback. Looks pretty much like what I want.

Comment: Yep, this is it. Thank you so much!